# Can you make only one class change onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build the battleship project, right now I've generated a 10x10 grid that looks like this:

[image]

But I want thst on each click in a box, it changes the color from cyan to black. I've tried doing this with a `useState` method but it changes all of the boxes. I want the boxes to be changed one by one after each click

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Ship from "../components/ShipGenerate.js";
import "../style/style.css";

function Grid(props) {
    let grid = new Array(10);
    let box = [];
    const [active, setActive] = useState(true);

    console.log(grid);
    console.log(box);
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i += 1) grid[i] = new Array(10).fill(0);

    const rnd = (r) => Math.trunc(Math.random() * r);

    for (let l = 0; l < 40; l += 1) {
        grid[rnd(10)][rnd(10)] = 1;
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
            if (grid[x][y] === 0) {
                box.push(
                    <div>
                        <div className="piece"></div>
                    </div>
                );
            } else {
                box.push(
                    <div>
                        <div className="boom"></div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="box">{box}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Grid;
```

Comment: Each box needs to have its own state. In other words, each grid location has a state: it's either empty, has a ship, or has a hit ship.

Comment: I copy and paste the provided source codes on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-demo-e4fvx?file=/src/Grid.js). Could you demonstrate the question with a minimal version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the whole grid as state.

Then when you click on a box, you pass the `x` and `y` coordinates to a function that flips the clicked box from 0 to 1 or viceversa - something like:

```js
function Grid(props) {
    const emptyGrid = new Array(10);
    for (let i = 0; i < emptyGrid.length; i += 1) {
        emptyGrid[i] = new Array(10).fill(0);
    }

    const [grid, setGrid] = useState(emptyGrid);

    function togglePieceStatus(x, y) {
        setGrid(currentGrid => {
            const position = currentGrid[x][y];
            currentGrid[x][y] = position === 0 ? 1 : 0;
            return currentGrid;
        });
    }

    const box = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
            const className = grid[x][y] === 0 ? 'piece' : 'boom';
            box.push(
                <div>
                    <div
                        className={className}
                        onClick={() => togglePieceStatus(x, y)}
                    ></div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="box">{box}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property '10' of undefined``` getting this error while doing it...